# Can "shavelings" be used to refer to Asian monks? Or does it only refer to Occidental shaven-headed church men?

Tags: word-usage

Can "shavelings" be used to refer to Asian monks? Or it only refers to Occidental shaven-headed church men?
Can a shaven-headed civilian be called a "shaveling"?

Comment: You can call them that if you like.  But if your hearers have not heard the term before (as I have not), it is not much use for communication.

Comment: Ditto. Precisely. If you're writing a science-fiction novel set on a different planet, you can make up your own names in context. But, while _shaveling_ has a transparent meaning, it's a fossil, and most English speakers will not have any experience of its specific history of use or reference. And it's _occidental_, just like _accidental_, except for the first vowel.

Comment: I am not going to use it in dailiy communication. I just want to know when,where,and how people use it, no matter historically or contemporarily:)

Comment: And, although it's off-topic, both Oriental and Occidental should be capitalized when they refer to the East and the West.  Plus, for whatever reason, "Oriental" isn't that PC when applied to a person; consider using "Asian".

Comment: I would tend to use "skinhead".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly *can*, but you might consider the fact that even fairly obscure words like "cenobite" and "skete" are both more specific and [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shaveling%2Ccenobite%2Cskete&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshaveling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccenobite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cskete%3B%2Cc0) than "shaveling"

Answer (score 2):

*Tonsured* is the word you are looking for. It refers specifically to cutting or shaving the hair of the head as an outward sign of a monastic vow, and in the Orthodox Christian sacrament of Chrismation.

Cenobite is a monk who lives in a monastic community, rather than as a hermit. Skete is a type of monastic community. Neither of those terms refer specifically to the shorn or shaved head.